# Aplicacion .net en visual studio 2017 come memoria

Tags: vb.net

Hola que tal? tengo una aplicación y cuando ingreso a una sección, exactamente un formulario, la memoria se expande hasta tildarse totalmente la computadora, quisiera saber como puedo determinar que función, o que subrutina me esta haciendo tal fenómeno, resulta que utilizo varias class, uno dentro de otra, todas hacen funciones diferentes, quiero saber porque no encuentro lógica posible para tal cosa, como puedo encontrar el problema, alguien me podría ayudar? muchas gracias
Detalles:
tengo una maquina virtual dedicada al visual studio 2017, con 4 gb de ram, la aplicacion normalmente ocupa 15 mb en memoria, pero de 15 salta a 400 mb y 1 gb y asi susesivamente.

Comment: ¿De cuanta memoria dispones en tu PC?Comprueba que no creas hilos o bucles infinitos.Aunque de todas formas tu mejor amigo siempre sera el Debugger no hay mejor forma de saber que esta pasando

Comment: tengo una maquina virtual dedicada al visual studio 2017, con 4 gb de ram, la aplicacion normalmente ocupa 15 mb en memoria, pero de 15 salta a 400 mb y 1 gb y asi susesivamente. el debugger muere tambien

Comment: 15 mb de memoria el VS? A mi abierto sin proyecto me consume solo 200 MB con proyecto abierto llega casi a las 500 MB, lo unico que se me ocurre son bucles mal configurados o hilos abiertos en segundo plano.¿Te da algun error al ejecutarlo? ¿Puedes pasar alguna foto del debugger para ver la curva de consumo de recursos?

Comment: Se tilda de tal manera que queda totalmente en blanco, 15mb ocupa el archivo exe del proyecto, tendría que hacer un punto de interrupción, supongo que es mi última salida pero no tengo mucho tiempo para hacerlo, l quería saber si existe algo más efectivo o alguna configuración,

Comment: *tendría que hacer un punto de interrupción* Es tu mejor opción sin ninguna duda. Y te va a tocar debuggear quieras o no, porque claramente, algún proceso te está generando bucles y por eso ese pico de actividad.

Comment: Sin ver absolutamente nada de código y sin tener una idea al menos de qué hace la aplicación, no podemos ayudarte. Esos memory leaks suelen tener que ver con recursos no liberados. Debes comprobar que todas las clases que implementen `IDisposable` son correctamente liberadas (usando `Dispose` o usando un bloque `using`).